# How to find the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2)^{20}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

How to find the coefficient of $x^4$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2)^{20}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Let us treat this trinomial
$$1+x+x^2$$
instead as a binomial:
$$=(1+x)+x^2$$
Then, by the binomial theorem, we have
$$(1+x+x^2)^{20}=\sum_{n=0}^{20} \binom{20}{n}x^{2n}(1+x)^{20-n}$$
Now notice that it in this sum, only the $n=0,1,2$ terms can have an $x^4$ term, because otherwise the $x^{2n}$ would produce some power of $x$ greater than $4$. Thus we need only to examine the terms
$$\binom{20}{0}(1+x)^{20}$$
$$\binom{20}{1}x^2(1+x)^{19}$$
$$\binom{20}{2}x^4(1+x)^{18}$$
Using the binomial theorem, from the first term, we have a coefficient of
$$\color{red}{\binom{20}{0}\binom{20}{4}}$$
Again using the binomial theorem, from the second term, we have a coefficient of
$$\color{red}{\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{2}}$$
and from the last term, it is rather obvious that the coefficient will be
$$\color{red}{\binom{20}{2}}$$
and so the final coefficient is
$$\color{red}{\binom{20}{0}\binom{20}{4}+\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{2}+\binom{20}{2}}$$

Comment: Using the binomial theorem, from the first term, we have a coefficient of
/binom {16} C{4} instead of (204) @Nilknarf

Comment: @SakuziMarkel No, I don't think so, because in the first term, $(1+x)$ is being raised to the  $20$th power, not the $16$th.

Comment: How the last term will be 1?@Nilknarf

Comment: Because the coefficient of the $x^4$ term of $x^4(1+x)^{18}$ is the same as the coefficient of the $x^0$ term in $(1+x)^{18}$, since $x^4\cdot x^0=x^4$.

Comment: @kingW3 Oh my god, what a ridiculously stupid mistake. Thank you so much for telling me! :P

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\left[x^n\right]\left(1+x+x^2\right)^{20}
&=\left[x^n\right]\left(\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\right)^{20}\\
&=\left[x^n\right]\overbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{20}\binom{20}{j}\left(-x^3\right)^j}^{\left(1-x^3\right)^{20}}\overbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-20}{k}(-x)^k\vphantom{\sum_{j=0}^{20}}}^{(1-x)^{-20}}\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}\binom{20}{j}\binom{-20}{n-3j}\tag{$k=n-3j$}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}(-1)^j\binom{20}{j}\binom{n-3j+19}{19}\\
\end{align}
$$
For $n=4$, there are just two term:
$$
\binom{20}{0}\binom{23}{19}-\binom{20}{1}\binom{20}{19}=8455
$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $f(x)=(1+x+x^2)^{20}$. Use the forth derivative for $x=0$ , that is $f^{''''}(0)$

If $c$ is the wanted coefficient, then $f^{''''}(x)=4! \cdot c + x \cdot g(x)$. Now making $x=0$ one gets $c = \frac {f^{''''}(0)}{4!}$

Comment: amazing, how simply you put it

Comment: fourth derivative will be way too lengthy @EugenCovaci

Comment: @SakuziMarkel No, you you know how to make it easy.

Comment: I don't know @EugenCovaci